# Django add fields to form dynamically based on number of values in model choice field

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, formsets

Objective:
From a Django Form, modelchoice field i am making the widget display multiple checkboxes. But for each checkbox I would like to display exactly one textbox and then submit. I need to know if the checkbox is not selected, it's id still and the possible textbox value. How do I acheive this, if it is Ajax. please elaborate. as I am fairly new to django and haven't worked much with ajax.

Comment: Could you give us more information about the model? Django can create the widgets automatically from the model, but it's not clear how do you plan to do that, if there's only one field or multiple.

Comment: The model is a M2M through model... basically a school app...and the problem model for me is those who are registered for a particular class..attendance register
What I am doing is first getting all the students registered for the class..which is a FK in a model. Then I need to display them individually to be checked/selected as present and those who are not present, I need to optionally give comments (textbox). This is the challenge how do I get the textbox to display for each student, and grab the appropriate student ID if they are not present.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to possible approaches here,

1. Simpler(but a very tardy approach):
   Submit the form after user's checkbox input, process the input in `views.py` and accordingly serve the other part of the form on a different template. This will lead you to reloading the page and changing URL's for the same form. This approach is fine if you are doing it only to learn Django at first.
2. The better approach. You can use on page JavaScript/JQuery to determine whether the checkbox is ticked or no and the accordingly show the checkbox. You can do something like

   ```
   if(document.getElementById('yourCheckBoxID').checked) 
   {
   $("#FormFieldID").show();
   } 
   else 
   {
   $("#FormFieldID").hide();
   }
   ```

If you are doing the latter, do remember to NOT set the input field as "required", as it may throw up errors when not showing the text field. Use some sort of JS form validation if you have to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks man...this thing been giving me a headache..will update you if i get thru...